# Swift CurrencyText library round financial values incorrect for Double

Tags: swift, excel, double

I have this double calculation 103.95 * 27.5 = **2858,625**

I use [CurrencyText](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CurrencyText) library for formatting my currency double values.

```
var formatter: CurrencyFormatter?

formatter = CurrencyFormatter {
    $0.currency = .dollar
    $0.currencySymbol = "$"
}

// total variable below is my Double value which is 2858,625

total.currencyFormatted(formatter: unwrappedFormatter)
```

I've extended Double with custom function the call of which you see above ^.

```
func currencyFormatted(formatter: CurrencyFormatter) -> String {
       
        let string = formatter.string(from: self)
        
        if let unwrappedString = string {
            return unwrappedString
        } else {
            return "No formatted currency"
        }
}
```

The formatter returns $2,858.62 value but looking at Excel where I have set the value **2858,625** to the cell and assigned **financial** format, looks like it should be **2858,63** as excel shows.

Is the library broken or I did smth wrong?

Also this "handmade" code:

```
var financialString: String? {
        
        Double.formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        Double.formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        Double.formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        
        if let result =  Double.formatter.string(for: self) {
            return result
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

returns **2858,62** as well

1. Who is right excel or library in financial calculation?
2. If excel right should I replace library or should I manage rounding by my self?

Comment: I am not sure there is _one_ right answer here, it can depend on the application and/or location

Comment: One is doing a "banker's rounding" while the other is doing a mathmatical rounding.  Banker's rounding will round the `.005` to the nearest even number so if the value was `2858,635` both rounding will return the same.  Excel uses mathmatical rounding which means `,005` will round up always.

Comment: @ScottCraner I guess I need Banker's rounding, thanks! which means 2858.62 is ok, right?

Comment: Then do not use Excel.  The worksheet formula rounding will not do banker's rounding.

Comment: @ScottCraner very strange for which purposes Excel team developed Number formatting options such as financial, currency, accounting if they round using mathematical rounding. but anyway thanks for help I understood